# Android How to Change countdown Timer values at runtime

Tags: android

I have a countdown timer running in my background service. My service starts in my MainActivity as given

```
startService(new Intent(this, BroadcastService.class));
```

In my BroadcastService oncreate() I am calling countdown timer and get it's count down time from sharedpref set by user. My problem is that user can change the time of countdown timer time. when user set countdown timer time i switch my Activity to MainActivity so service should again call and Countdown timer should set for it's new value. But on Calling MainActivity countdown timer is not setting it's value for new time. What I am doing wrong.

### BroadCastService

```
public class BroadcastService extends Service {

    private final static String TAG = "BroadcastService";
    DataManager dm_obj;
    private NotificationManager mManager;
    String check_time_format,check_current_time;
    long difference;
    public static final String COUNTDOWN_BR = "com.example.wajibati.countdown_br";
    Intent bi = new Intent(COUNTDOWN_BR);
    boolean check_daylight_saving;
    CountDownTimer cdt = null;
    int time_format;
    int alarm_type;
    boolean isIshaFinished;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {       
        super.onCreate();

        dm_obj=new DataManager(getApplicationContext());
        isIshaFinished=false;
        Log.i(TAG, "Starting timer...");
        time_format=dm_obj.loadTimeFormat();
        check_daylight_saving=dm_obj.loadDaylight();
        if(time_format==0){
            check_time_format="hh:mm aa";

        }else{

            check_time_format="kk:mm";
        }
        CalculateTimedifference();
        RunCountDownTimer();


    }


## MainActivity ##

    public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       startService(new Intent(this, BroadcastService.class));
      }

       private BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {            
            updateGUI(intent); // or whatever method used to update your GUI fields
        }
    };
    @Override  
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();        
        registerReceiver(br, new   IntentFilter(BroadcastService.COUNTDOWN_BR));

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(br);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        try {
            unregisterReceiver(br);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Receiver was probably already stopped in onPause()
        }
        super.onStop();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {        
        stopService(new Intent(this, BroadcastService.class));

        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: please post relevant code

Comment: code for background service is posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because when you can startService() from MainActivity second time the BroadcastService is already running, so OnCreate() method of the service does not get called in which you are calling your count down timer.

Probably you should replace your code from onCreate() to onStartCommand() in your service.

Comment: you do not have to call onStartCommand() method. It is the method of android.app.Service class, when you will call startService() it will get called by the system itself.

Comment: in my given code where i have to change can you please pointout

Comment: In your Service Override onStartCommand() method, and put everything which is inside onCreate() to onStartCommand().